# "Undefined is not a function" with Tablesorter in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, tablesorter

I'm trying to use Tablesorter on a Rails view. The haml for the view is:

```
- @page_title = 'Users'
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function()
      {
          $("#data_table").tablesorter();
      }
  );
%table#data_table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Username
      %th Email
      %th Role
      %th Internal
      %th
  %tbody
    - @users.each do |user|
      %tr{:class => cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')}
        %td= user.username
        %td= user.email
        %td= user.role_name
        %td= user.internal
        %td{:class => 'list_actions'}
          = link_to 'Show', user
          %br/
          = link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user)
          %br/
          = link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
%br/
```

My `application.js` has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.tablesorter
//= require_tree .
```

When I load the page, the JavaScript console shows an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line `$("#data_table").tablesorter();`. Others reporting a similar problem say it could be because of jQuery loading twice, but I don't know how to tell whether that's happening or what to do about it within the Rails structure (I don't know JavaScript or jQuery at all yet).

How do I go about fixing this?

Edit: I should mention that the `jquery` and `jquery.tablesorter` JavaScript files are in app/assets/javascripts.

Comment: To see if its including jquery twice just view the generated page's source and see if there is more than one jquery being included

Comment: In addition you could also check that tablesorter plugin script is added **after** jquery.

Comment: Ah, obvious when you know what you're doing! :)

Yes, it was loading 2 copies, the one I'd put in app/assets/javascripts and another one that's coming from I don't know where (the source says "assets/jquery.js', but it doesn't seem to be in any of my assets directories).